# Flex-slots intermittently unable to execute trivial queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running some tests using flex-slots. I have created a flex-slot commitment/reservation of 100 using `QUERY` as the type, and assigned it to my project. There have no other queries running concurrently. I am using a trivial query without cached results and mode set to `INTERACTIVE` to test performance. Everything is running in the US multi-region.

The table I am querying has just 1.2M rows (only 86MB), and is the public wikipedia dataset found in `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki1M`.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(views) AS total_views,
  title,
  LANGUAGE
FROM
  `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki1M`
WHERE
  LANGUAGE='en'
  AND TITLE LIKE "%Germany%"
GROUP BY
  title,
  LANGUAGE
ORDER BY
  total_views DESC;
```

A successful run (e.g. `bquxjob_1f741592_1853646efb9`) runs in under 1 second and uses on average less than a single slot. 100 slots for this query should be more than adequate.

[image]

However, intermittently the query (e.g. `bquxjob_1913d525_185365564ea`) fails with:

```
"Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, or using more efficient logic in this job."
```

[image]

[image]

Is there a reason why this trivial query would be failing even with 100 slots assigned and no other queries running concurrently?

Comment: Hi @Graham Polley, This error may be caused due to the use of ORDER BY clause which is an expensive operation. Can you increase the flex slots and try again? Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Shipra. Yes, totally agree that `ORDER_BY` is expensive (results need to be shuffled to one node for final ordering), but this is a small dataset and should be easy with 100 slots. In addition, when it does run successfully, I can see that it's not using even close to the allocated 100 slots.

Comment: Hi @Graham Polley, For your requirement, I would suggest you increase the slots since the issue seems to be related to shuffle quota which is linearly correlated to the number of slots available in the project. This quota cannot be increased but to get more quota you need to provision more slots. Another workaround is to reduce the data processing for which you can refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-communication). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Shipra. There are 100 slots available for this query. It's more than adequate for such a trivial query. We can see when it executes successfully, it also uses < 1 slot!

Comment: Hi @Graham Polley, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)